# Does R Markdown follow the same style guideline rules as R?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I've read a lot of style guidelines for R and they all say to use spaces after commas, between equal signs and stuff like that. Yet the default R Studio R Markdown document ignores the rules. Why do I have to remember one set of style guidelines for my `*.R` files and another for my `*.Rmd`?

````
# EXPECTED
```{r setup, include = FALSE}

# ACTUAL
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
````

Comment: Is it fine to use `\`\`\`{r setup, include = FALSE}` in my R Markdown? There must be a reason the R Studio team chose to ignore this spacing guideline when creating their default R Markdown document.

Comment: It's fine with spaces. I'm using that

Comment: In the RStudio preferences `Code`-->`Completion` tab, there's an option `Insert space around equals for argument completions`. When this is checked, it inserts spaces around `=` in function arguments, but it doesn't appear to affect `rmarkdown` chunk options. Perhaps you could go to the [RStudio development site on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues) and suggest adding a similar option for code chunks in the `R markdown` preferences tab as an enhancement .